# Overriding default validation for DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a custom validation attribute for DateTime that inherits from **RequiredAttribute**. For some reason, some type of built in DateTime validation in MVC is overriding my custom validation because I keep getting the error message "The value 'dd' is not valid for Date" when I type in dd as the value for the date. How do I get it use my custom validator so that my own error message gets displayed instead?

View Model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DateValidation(ErrorMessage = "A valid date is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Validator

```
public class DateValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime dt;

        return DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dt);
    }
}
```

In response to Lars' answer:
How do I get it to use the error message created in the validation attribute of my model so i can create different error messages for different model properties that use this same validation attribute?

Comment: can you post the code for your model with your attribute?

Comment: I have a posted a shortened version of my code

Answer (score 0):

Inside `IsValid` you can change the `ErrorMessage`:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    ErrorMessage = "Date is invalid.";
```

Comment: How do I get it to use the error message created in the validation attribute of my model so i can create different error messages for different model properties that use this same validation attribute?